# Poincaré disk model of hyperbolic plane

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Can someone please explain trigonometry in  Equations (2) to (8) of:

[PoincareDisk](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoincareHyperbolicDisk.html) ?

Comment: there it is not clear to me what do they mean by $\theta_2$ ??

Comment: it's not clear to me what the calculations on the page your link points to are supposed to mean. There is no clear statement what they intend to demonstrate or illustrate, and the it is not explained what the quantities they are using are representing. What exactly is it you want to have explained?

Comment: I agree, It appears that the horizontal dashed  line is the x-axis. Also $ \phi +d\theta = \pi /2$.

Answer (score 0):

It is just basic geometry (nothing hyperbolic)

- the boundary circle is the unit circle
- $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the angles from the x-axis to the ideal points of the hyperbolic line. (the points where the arc meets the boundary circle)

Then:

- $\phi$  is the angle from the x-axis to the centre of the orthogonal circle.
- $d\phi$  is the angle from $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$ to the angle $\phi$.
- $r$  is the distance from $\phi_1$ or $\phi_2$ to the centre of the orthogonal circle. (and thus the radius of the orthogonal  circle)
- $R$  is the distance from the origin to the centre of the orthogonal circle.

nothing really interesting I thought

Comment: Are 7 tagged equations needed to show orthogonal circle angles  complementary?

Comment: 3 and 8 are obvious (8 could be better formulated as complementary angle to $d\phi$. 4 and 6 are interesting, I was thinking to add them to the wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model but there was no logical place to put them (there is no mention of ideal points in the whole article, yet)